# Choose from foreign keys in rails admin not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

Following is my models:

```
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :published, :title

  validates :published, :presence => true
  validates :title, :presence => true,
                    :length => { :minimum => 10 }

  has_many :choice, :dependent => :destroy
end


class Choice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :poll
  attr_accessible :choice_text, :votes

  validates :choice_text, :presence => true

end
```

I then tried to install the [rails admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/). I was able to create the choices and polls in the admin, but i was unable to associate a choice with a poll and vice versa.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all in **has_many** class name should be in plural:

```
has_many :choices
```

And you should add **attr_accessible poll_id** or **choice_ids** for Model from which you want to edit this association. Or just delete all **attr_accessible** for first try.

```
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :published, :title, choice_ids

  validates :published, :presence => true
  validates :title, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 10 }

  has_many :choices, :dependent => :destroy
end


class Choice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :poll
  attr_accessible :choice_text, :votes, :poll_id

  validates :choice_text, :presence => true

end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `attr_accessible` in Rails 4. Use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` instead. More info: 
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Belongs-to-association